# Create a process not an application in C#

Tags: c#, process, taskmanager

I've created a simple application that I wish to be a process and not show up as an application inside taskmanager, simply because it is not an application. It was intended to be a process.

Comment: ...you mean a service? Perhaps a _Windows Service_?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to read about Windows Services.

[Walkthrough: Creating a Windows Service Application in the Component Designer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zt39148a%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

[Creating a C# Service Step-by-Step: Lesson I](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/3938/Creating-a-C-Service-Step-by-Step-Lesson-I)

You don't give much information about what you application does, but either Console or Forms will be displayed on the TaskManager, and even as a process it will be shown over the Processes tab so I'm not sure what are your intentions with this.

Comment: Okay thank you, I realize that a Service is what I was going for. Thank you very much!